# AWS: i want to store all my data on EBS partition. Is it a good practise or should store on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and trying to understand it.

Presently i have a small Django App.

I am planning to have an EC2 instance of type t3.small (2 cpus and 2 GB ram)

I will have the following EBS storages:

1) EBS root system: 10GB (mainly used for OS and other config files)

2) Attached EBS: 20GB (mainly used to store all the code and images and videos etc)

I will keep taking snapshot of both the EBS volumes daily.

I want my images and videos only accessible from the EC2 instance.

So Is this approach a good approach. or i have to use S3/

Comment: you dont _have_ to use S3. But you should consider storing static content (which would rarely change) onto S3 so that you can leverage the delivery by cloudfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go for storing in S3 for many reasons :

- Duarbility : S3 is 99,99999999 (11x9). Data is replicated in all AZ of the selected region. You can also easily setup a Cross Region Replication for better data durability and security.
- Price: You pay only for the disk space you're using it. You don't have to specify a volume size like with EBS.
- Scalibility : You add data as you go and the bucket will scale to infinite.
  If your application become successful and you have more traffic you should go to a horizontal scaling using AutoScaling and LoadBalancer and that means multiple EC2 instances. In that case it will be so easier to access Data on S3 instead on an EBS attached to an instance.

Comment: Should i put all my source code i.e my Django project folder and also static content in S3. And dont need to use EBS at all

Comment: No only static files should go in S3. You can also setup later CloudFront (a CDN) to accelerate the access to these files.

Comment: So we will need to use both EBS and S3. But should i use the root partition to store the code or on an attached EBS